# IPFS http response got EOF error with correct body occasionally

Tags: go, ipfs

When I debug in the following [code](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api/blob/7009904238640459874f3dff161ceb26caf458c8/request.go#L51), sometimes it can read data from the body correctly but with **EOF** error.

```
func (r *trailerReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.resp.Body.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        if e := r.resp.Trailer.Get("X-Stream-Error"); e != "" {
            err = errors.New(e)
        }
    }
    return n, err
}
```

I called [this method](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api/blob/7009904238640459874f3dff161ceb26caf458c8/mfs.go#L278) in my code:

```
// FilesRead read a file in a given MFS
func (s *Shell) FilesRead(ctx context.Context, path string, options ...FilesOpt) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    rb := s.Request("files/read", path)
    for _, opt := range options {
        if err := opt(rb); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    resp, err := rb.Send(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if resp.Error != nil {
        return nil, resp.Error
    }

    return resp.Output, nil
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts... If you're running the daemon on a low-memory machine, it may crash in the background. Might want to make sure that isn't the case.

Comment: I checked that, the daemon doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stebalien said in this [Github issue](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api/issues/223), it's a go's expected behavior of `Reader`.

Refer to the third paragraph of this [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)

> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read. It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The next Read should return 0, EOF.